# Image not showing in blade

Tags: laravel

I have been working on an open source project recently, currently I am  just adding new features in the project.

The project has some images to retrieve and to display them in the view blade that is working perfectly but when I am trying to add a new image through the form, my images are not displaying.
What could be the problem

I have tried

```
php artisan storage:link
```

But without success

Comment: check whether images exist in storage/public/ path

Comment: Yes they do , they are being added in the storage

Comment: try deleting generated shortcut from public folder  and then run again php artisan storage:link

Comment: is it solved your issue ?

Comment: @John yes thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is when you upload laravel application from one sever to another or from local to live server .It copies shortcut of storage folder too.So before you must delete shortcut folder from `public/storage` and symbolic link again.

To make these files accessible from the web, you should create a `symbolic link` from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`.

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk